# Sum all values row-wise conditionally grouped by id

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sum, pandas-groupby

My end goal is to sum all minutes only from **initial** to **final** in column periods. This needs to be grouped by id

I have thousands of id and not all of them have the same amount of min in between initial and final.

Periods are sorted in a "journey" fashion each record represents a period of time of its id

Pseudocode:

Iterate rows and sum all values in column "min"
if sum starts in periods == initial and ends in periods = final

Example with 2 ids

| id | periods | min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | period_x | 10 |
| 1 | initial | 2 |
| 1 | progress | 3 |
| 1 | progress_1 | 4 |
| 1 | final | 5 |
| 2 | period_y | 10 |
| 2 | period_z | 2 |
| 2 | initial | 3 |
| 2 | progress_1 | 20 |
| 2 | final | 3 |

Desired output

| id | periods | min | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | period_x | 10 | 14 |
| 1 | initial | 2 | 14 |
| 1 | progress | 3 | 14 |
| 1 | progress_1 | 4 | 14 |
| 1 | final | 5 | 14 |
| 2 | period_y | 10 | 26 |
| 2 | period_z | 2 | 26 |
| 2 | initial | 3 | 26 |
| 2 | progress_1 | 20 | 26 |
| 2 | final | 3 | 26 |

So far I've tried:

```
L = ['initial' 'final']
df['sum'] = df.id.where( df.zone_name.isin(L)).groupby(df['if']).transform('sum')
```

But this doesn't count what is in between initial and final

Comment: The id of first row also 1, so it is confusing grouping by id excluding first row (computer).

Comment: is this an accurate representation of your actual data?

Comment: True. But how do I exclude all rows that are outside (initial - final) In my dataset there is many more

Comment: @servando If there is only one (initial - final), you already know row number of 'initial' and 'final', right?

Comment: It's a small subset of my actual data (anonymized). Each id has many different periods. I just want to sum up whatever is the min initial all the way to min final @sophocles

Comment: @SangkeunPark Not sure if i understand. Consider hundreds of ids and several periods "above" initial and below "final". Dataset is sorted in a "journey" fashion

Comment: @servando It would be nice to provide more detailed sample data and desired output. Now I am not sure if it is helpufl `df['sum'] = df.loc[1:5, 'min'].sum()`

Comment: @SangkeunPark Thanks! I'm going to edit my question and try to provide more info. Your answer is not quite what I'm looking for. Because I have thousands of ids and not all of them have progress and progress_1 in between initial and final

Comment: @servando Yes, that's why I ask you more info :)

Answer (score 2):

Create groups using `cumsum` and then return the sum of group 1, then apply that sum to the entire column. "Group 1" is anything per id that is between initial and final:

```
import numpy as np
df['grp'] = df['periods'].isin(['initial','final'])
df['grp'] = np.where(df['periods'] == 'final', 1, df.groupby('id')['grp'].cumsum())
df['sum'] = np.where(df['grp'].eq(1), df.groupby(['id', 'grp'])['min'].transform('sum'), np.nan)
df['sum'] = df.groupby('id')['sum'].transform(max)
df
Out[1]: 
   id     periods  min  grp   sum
0   1    period_x   10    0  14.0
1   1     initial    2    1  14.0
2   1    progress    3    1  14.0
3   1  progress_1    4    1  14.0
4   1       final    5    1  14.0
5   2    period_y   10    0  26.0
6   2    period_z    2    0  26.0
7   2     initial    3    1  26.0
8   2  progress_1   20    1  26.0
9   2       final    3    1  26.0
```